# Android application crashing when adding button in

Tags: android, button

Right I'm stuck, and very puzzled. I have created an app and it works fine in every other way, however I am having issues with buttons in a couple of the pages.

I have copied the java and xml from pages I know work. but it doesn't solve the issue. If i take all the buttons out of the java file it compiles and runs and loads the page.

However if I put the button text (that works with every other page) back in it then doesn't load the page when i start the activity

This is the error log

```
05-09 13:19:33.724: D/AndroidRuntime(896): Shutting down VM
05-09 13:19:33.724: W/dalvikvm(896): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x2bc9a300)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:     Unable to find explicit activity class {com.british.sheep/com.british.sheep.mix}; have you     declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at com.british.sheep.colour$4.onClick(colour.java:62)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-09 13:19:33.735: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Like i say i know the button code works as i have used it for many other apps perfectly. so im stuck. the rest of the code works its just when i add the buttons in.

What could this be

```
public class creamy extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  //makes full screen and takes away title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //
    setContentView(R.layout.creamy);
       Button wensleydale = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wensleydale);
    wensleydale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), wensleydale.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }


            }); 
}
//code for menu add to all pages 
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.text:     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
        case R.id.cat:  
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), creamy.class));
        break;
        case R.id.ato:  
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), atoz.class));
        break;
    }
    return true;    
}
//end code for menu  


 }
```

Thats the activity code, it is the same as the other activity that i know works except the class name and set content view layout

Comment: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.british.sheep/com.british.sheep.mix}; have you     declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Please search in google before asking question...Answer is there in the Exception it self

Comment: Make sure very class that extends Activity are declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

**Declaire your activity in your manifest**

```
<activity android:name="com.british.sheep.mix" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Comment: wensleydale is already in the manfest, and its not when i click on the wensleydale button its when i click on the button to run mix activity

Answer (score 0):

add `wensleydale.class` in android manifest file:

```
<activity  android:name=".wensleydale"/>
```

if you have already declare then try using package name:

```
<activity  android:name="com.test.wensleydale"/>
```

whatever your package name.

Comment: right so i had already declared it in the manifest but deleted it, compiled it and re added it exactly how it was before and this time no crash...